# How to define the status text for a CustomAction in InstallExecuteSequence?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a installer with several custom actions such as:

```
<CustomAction Id="INSTALL_DRIVERS_32" Directory="DIR_DRIVERS" ExeCommand='"[DIR_DRIVERS]install_32_drivers.bat"' Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore" />
<CustomAction Id="INSTALL_DRIVERS_64" Directory="DIR_DRIVERS" ExeCommand='"[DIR_DRIVERS]install_64_drivers.bat"' Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="ignore" />
```

In the install sequence:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="INSTALL_DRIVERS_32" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[NOT VersionNT64 AND NOT Installed]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="INSTALL_DRIVERS_64" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[VersionNT64 AND NOT Installed]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I want to show the user what the installer is doing:

[image]

How can I do it?

I'm using a `WixUI_InstallDir` UI, and I would like not to break the default layout. I've also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724724/1485885) but I don't understand how to do it (also, I don't need to update dynamically the status, just to show a text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely need to add a `ProgressText` element for that custom action. It should work if you have that custom action name as the `Action`, then the message text.

---

For example, under the `UI` element:

```
<ProgressText Action="INSTALL_DRIVERS_32">Installing drivers</ProgressText>
```

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly, I've updated your answer to add the snippet that I've used based on your indications